# uniform convergence of subsequences

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have the following question. 
Given a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ for which there is a subsequence of functions uniformly converging to some $\overline{f}(x)$. What can we say about $f_n(x)$? What additional assumption is needed to ensure uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you need to know the space your functions are on, for a start: any pointwise convergent sequence of functions from a finite set to $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly convergent, for example...

Answer (score 2):

There is a subsequence converging uniformly to $\overline{f}(x)$, but this says nothing at all about the members of the sequence that are not in the subsequence.

If you want the whole sequence to converge, you need some 
assumption that gives you control over the other members of the sequence.
For example, it would be sufficient that every subsequence has a subsequence that converges uniformly to $\overline{f}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Not much can be said about $f_n$; for example, consider $f_n(x)=n$ if $n$ is odd and $f_n(x)=1/n$ if $n$ is even. The subsequence $f_{2n}$ clearly converges uniformly to $0$, but $f_n$ doesn't even converge pointwise.

Comment: I see thank you for your comments. Actually, my case is very particular. The sequence I am dealing with is the sequence generated by considering a polygonal arcs obtained by making smaller and smaller the mesh.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but I would think your sequence converges uniformly from the start.